# How can make filters apply to dimensions in several crossfilter instances?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm using some very simplified data to illustrate the idea here.. Suppose my data set is:

```
var data = 
[{type:"cat",row:1, col:1, speed:15},
{type:"cat",row:1, col:2, speed:10},
{type:"cat",row:2, col:1, speed:3},
{type:"cat",row:2, col:2, speed:17},
{type:"dog",row:1, col:1, speed:25},
{type:"dog",row:1, col:2, speed:30},
{type:"dog",row:2, col:1, speed:16},
{type:"dog",row:2, col:2, speed:10}]
```

I have several dimensions on this data, for example

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
var mainDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return [+d.row, +d.col];
});
var mainGroup = mainDim.group().reduceSum(function (d) {
    return +d.speed;
});
var rowDim = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.row;
});
var rowGroup = rowDim.group();
```

There are several DC.JS charts build using this data set.

Now the issue is, I wanted a way to generate charts dynamically, for example generating a heatMap for each `type`. I couldn't figure out a way to do this with only a single crossfilter instance, so instead I created filtered data sets with their own crossfiter instances, dimensions, groups etc.

```
// Get list of unique types
var types = [];
data.forEach( function(d) { 
    if( types.indexOf(d.type ) == -1 )
        types.push(d.type); 
});


// Create new dataset for each type
var filteredData = {};
function checkType(elem, type){
    return elem.type == type;
}
types.forEach(function(type){
    filteredData[type] = data.filter(function(elem){ 
        return checkType(elem,type);
    });
});

var crossfilters = {};
var dims = {};
var grps = {};
types.forEach(function(type){
    // Create crossfilter for each type
    crossfilters[type] = crossfilter(filteredData[type]);

    // Create dimensions & for each type
    dims[type] = crossfilters[type].dimension(function (d) {
        return [+d.row, +d.col];
    });

    grps[type] = dims[type].group().reduceSum(function (d) {
        return +d.speed;
    });
});
```

I would still like the users interactions with the charts to propagate filters between the different crossfilter instances. Is there a way to achieve this dynamically?

[jsfiddle with working demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/gg5oc884/9/)